# How can I make Polymer treat my custom icons the same as their own?

Tags: html, css, svg, polymer

I've been trying to find a clever way of using the  tag with my own svg icons so I could use the css property "fill: currentcolor;".

Using their built in icons like this: 
`<core-icon icon="android"></core-icon>` generates the whole svg for the icon, but using my own icon like this:     `<core-icon src="symbols/arrow-up.svg"></core-icon>` generates just a div with an svg background. Check out the screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm16R.png

It would be awesome if I could write `<core-icon icon="arrow-up"></core-icon>` for my own icon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `core-iconset-svg` to create your own icon set. Here's a guide explaining it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfiOJP8vuX4&index=2&list=PLOU2XLYxmsII5c3Mgw6fNYCzaWrsM3sMN

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm. Have you thought of automizing it like the svgstore grunt task does? [Chris Coyier demos it here and it looks sweet.](http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/). A combo would be the optimal way to work with icons on the web in my opinion.

Comment: That's a great idea. It could be a pretty sweet open source project for anyone who wants to take a crack :D

Comment: Most definitely. I'll let you know if I stumble upon it or make it myself.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create your own Iconset element like https://github.com/Polymer/core-icons/blob/master/device-icons.html this makes it very easy to use your custom icons.